# Is there way to find points on a folium map that are within a specified range?

Tags: python, visualization, folium

I have created a folium map with two different markers, `green` for company A and `red` for Company B.

I have successfully plotted them, but now I am trying to create circles on the map which will only show up if the points on Company A and B are within 500 mile of each other.

Any help about the direction I should be searching for answer would be helpful.

PS: Functions like `Folium.Circle` wouldn't work as I need circle only when two points are within a specified range.

Comment: Where is this circle needs to be drawn? And why not just calculate the distance between two companies and check if it is less than 500 mile

Comment: @darthbaba Hi, I need to draw circles to present in a nice visual manner, so that the end-user can see which two points can be merged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not understand where you want to draw the circle, I assumed that you want to draw the circle from the midpoint of both the companies and the circle will be of radius equal to half of the distance between 2 companies. Considering these assumptions I have written two helper functions `draw_circle` and `midpoint` these functions will return a circle GeoJson object and midpoint lat-long values. Make sure you have installed geopy, geog and shapely libraries in your python environment.

```
import math
from geopy.distance import geodesic
import folium
from shapely.geometry import Point
import numpy as np
import geog

def draw_circle(long, lat, n_points, radius):
    # n_point is the number of points to use to draw the circle
    d = radius*1609.34 # Miles
    p = shapely.geometry.Point([long, lat])
    angles = np.linspace(0, 360, n_points)
    polygon = geog.propagate(p, angles, d)
    return shapely.geometry.Polygon(polygon)


def midpoint(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    lat1 = math.radians(x1)
    lon1 = math.radians(y1)
    lat2 = math.radians(x2)
    dlon = math.radians(y2-y1)

    bx = math.cos(lat2) * math.cos(dlon)
    by = math.cos(lat2) * math.sin(dlon)
    lat3 = math.atan2(math.sin(lat1) + math.sin(lat2), \
           math.sqrt((math.cos(lat1) + bx) * (math.cos(lat1) \
           + bx) + by**2))
    lon3 = lon1 + math.atan2(by, math.cos(lat1) + bx)

    return [math.degrees(lat3), math.degrees(lon3)]
```

Drawing the maps:

```
coords_1 = (12.9716, 77.5946)
coords_2 = (15.2993, 74.1240)

# Base Map
india_map = folium.Map(location=[21, 78], zoom_start=5,prefer_canvas=True)
# Calculate Midpoint for the Circle to be drawn
mm = midpoint(coords_1[0],coords_1[1], coords_2[0], coords_2[1])
# Distance in miles between two pairs of Lat/Long values
distance = geodesic(coords_1, coords_2).miles

if  distance < 500:
    # Distance is less than 500 miles draw a Circle
    poly = draw_circle(mm[1], mm[0], 100, distance/2)
    style1 = {'color': 'green','weight': 2,"opacity":1,'fillOpacity':0,'interactive':False}
    folium.Marker(
        location=list(coords_1),
        icon=folium.Icon(color="red"),
    ).add_to(india_map)

    folium.Marker(
        location=list(coords_2),
        icon=folium.Icon(color="blue"),
    ).add_to(india_map)
    folium.GeoJson(poly,style_function=lambda x: style1).add_to(india_map)

else:
    folium.Marker(
        location=list(coords_1),
        icon=folium.Icon(color="red"),
    ).add_to(india_map)

    folium.Marker(
        location=list(coords_2),
        icon=folium.Icon(color="blue"),
    ).add_to(india_map)

india_map.save(outfile= "test.html")
```

Output:
[image: Distance less than 500]

You can play around with the style1 dictionary to achieve the kind of circle you wanted.